# How to determine when IE (Internet Explorer) browser is opened in my BHO?

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, com, atl, bho

I write a plugin for IE: **when IE is opened**, my plugin will automatic show a dialog to interactive with user. But I cannot determine which function will be called (that I will implement) when IE is opened. Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

I've written the plugin like this turtorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37044/Writing-a-BHO-in-Plain-C. But it is only run when user click on its item on IE's gear. I want to this plugin runs when IE is opening.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IE will call your [IObjectWithSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)::SetSite() implementation.  That is the first interaction you will have with the browser.

**Take note**: You may or may not be able to show a dialog at this point.  IE's startup process is complex and highly asynchronous.  You may hang if you try to show a dialog too early.  If that is the case, you should post an async message back to yourself to show the dialog a little bit later.  Alternatively you can sink [DWebBrowserEvents2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)::DocumentComplete and show your dialog when the first page load completes.

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented SetSite. But my BHO only run when user click on my BHO's item on IE's gear. I want my BHO will run when IE is run (maybe late), it doesn't need user to click on IE's gear.

Comment: My BHO cannot sink any event if it isn't created. I saw that, my BHO is created when user click on its item in gear for first time (create BHO and call SetSite) and call Exc for others time.

Comment: Are you registering your BHO properly in the registry?  It should get automatically created when the process loads.  If you're not being created until the button is clicked that implies you have only registered as a toolbar button extension, which is not the same thing as a BHO.  If your package has a BHO and a toolbar button extension, you should have two different IObjectWithSite implementations.

Comment: Thanks. I just think so. So, how to registering my BHO properly? I'm trying with google.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. This tutorial save my life: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37044/Writing-a-BHO-in-Plain-C.

Just write a normal BHO. Then install it.
Installing the BHO merely requires that a process calls our BHO's DllRegisterServer function. This is made simple via the regsvr32.exe utility. Simply run the command regsvr32.exe , and the BHO should be registered. To uninstall the BHO, a process needs to call our BHO's DllUnregisterServer function. This can also be accomplished via regsvr32.exe by running the command regsvr32.exe /u .